# Creating a registry key with path components via PowerShell

Tags: windows, powershell, registry, powershell-remoting

For a legacy application, I need to create a registry key with a name in the format `c:/foo/bar/baz`.  (Note: forward slashes, not backslashes.)  To be clear: that is a single key's name, with forward slashes, that otherwise looks like a Windows path.  Because I need to script this against lots of servers, PowerShell seems like a great option.

The problem is that I cannot figure out how to create a key in that format via PowerShell.  `New-Item -Path HKLM:\SOFTWARE\Some\Key -Name 'c:/foo/bar/baz'` errors out with PowerShell thinking I'm using `/` as a path separator and failing to find the path `HKLM:\Software\Some\Key\c:\foo\bar`, which does indeed not exist (and shouldn't).  I can't find any other way to (ab)use `New-Item` to get what I want.

Is there something I'm missing, or should I give up and just generate and load a registry dump the old-fashioned way?

Answer (score 18, accepted):

You need to do two things. First you need to get a writable `RegistryKey` object, otherwise you can't modify anything anyway. Second, use the `CreateSubKey` method on the `RegistryKey` object directly.

```
$writable = $true
$key = (get-item HKLM:\).OpenSubKey("SOFTWARE", $writable).CreateSubKey("C:/test")
$key.SetValue("Item 1", "Value 1")
```

After you create the key you use the resulting object to add values to it.

Comment: I thought FogBugz had keys like this, but the slashes go the other way: http://i42.tinypic.com/154jzac.jpg

Comment: @DannyTuppeny You guessed the software, but they're actually forward slashes in my original question.  PowerShell is just using the fact that UNC paths treat "\" and "/" identically to make my life annoying.

Comment: @BenjaminPollack Oops, didn't read the question properly! Seems like this "helpful" feature might make it impossible to do natively. You could call out to .NET, but obviously that's not ideal :-(

Comment: in powershell there is no such things as calling "out to .net". Powershell is 100% .net.

Comment: @StefanRusek I was referring to using the .NET classes directly rather than the PowerShell cmdlets/providers :-)