# Backspace and PowerShell

Tags: powershell

There is a key

```
HKLM:\SOFTWARE\Microsoft\Windows\CurrentVersion\WINEVT\Channels\Microsoft-Windows-Application-Experience/Program-Compatibility-Assistant
```

which contains Microsoft-Windows-Application-Experience/Program-Compatibility-Assistant in its path.
I have to set 0 value

```
New-ItemProperty -Path HKLM:\SOFTWARE\Microsoft\Windows\CurrentVersion\WINEVT\Channels\Microsoft-Windows-Application-Experience/Program-Compatibility-Assistant -Name Enabled -Value 0 -Force
```

But the only way to set a value due backspace is

```
[Microsoft.Win32.RegistryKey]::OpenRemoteBaseKey("LocalMachine", $COMPUTERNAME).OpenSubKey("SOFTWARE\Microsoft\Windows\CurrentVersion\WINEVT\Channels\Microsoft-Windows-Application-Experience/Steps-Recorder", $true).SetValue("Enabled", 0)
```

Is there any solution to avoid .NET Framework?

Comment: What do you mean "set a value due backspace"?

Comment: @JeffZeitlin Pretty sure that they meant forward slash. `Microsoft-Windows-Application-Experience/Program-Compatibility-Assistant`

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to create a registry entry with a forward slash in the name](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18218835/how-to-create-a-registry-entry-with-a-forward-slash-in-the-name)

Comment: Adi Inbar's answer has the way to add the character. Alternately you can get the item with getting the parent key, then using where object to filter the name then piping that to `set-itemproperty`. `gci 'HKLM:\SOFTWARE\Microsoft\Windows\CurrentVersion\WINEVT\Channels\' | Where-Object {.name -like '*Microsoft-Windows-Application-Experience/Program-Compatibility-Assistant'} | Set-ItemProperty -Name Enabled -Value 0 -Force`

Comment: I doesnt't work. Console doesn't display any error, but the value does not change.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
New-ItemProperty -Path HKLM:\SOFTWARE\Microsoft\Windows\CurrentVersion\WINEVT\Channels\Microsoft-Windows-Application-Experience\Program-Compatibility-Assistant -Name Enabled -Value 0 -Force
```

windows doesn't have much difference in `'/'` & `'\'` , few things may break here and there but you can open c:\windows and c:/Windows equally.

So try using the `\` .