# Creating a new registry folder with a space AND a forward slash in the folder name

Tags: windows, powershell, registry

I'm trying to create a new registry folder but the path I was to create contains a space and I'm not sure how to escape this to create the path correctly.

The path I'm trying to create is:

HKLM:\SYSTEM\CurrentControlSet\Control\SecurityProviders\SCHANNEL\Ciphers\RC4 64/128 (with a single folder called 'RC4(space)64/128' as the end of the path)

As you can see there is a space between RC4 and 64/128 (and **also** a slash between 64 and 128).

I have tried the following in powershell:

```
md "HKLM:\SYSTEM\CurrentControlSet\Control\SecurityProviders\SCHANNEL\Ciphers\RC4 64$([char]0x2215)128"
```

and

```
md "HKLM:\SYSTEM\CurrentControlSet\Control\SecurityProviders\SCHANNEL\Ciphers\RC4 64\/128"
```

But neither of these work.

The issue is that I need BOTH a space AND a forward slash in the resulting registry key folder name, as described above.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Creating a registry key with path components via PowerShell](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/16149175/creating-a-registry-key-with-path-components-via-powershell)

Answer (score 1):

```
([Microsoft.Win32.RegistryKey]::OpenRemoteBaseKey([Microsoft.Win32.RegistryHive]::LocalMachine, $env:COMPUTERNAME)).CreateSubKey('SYSTEM\CurrentControlSet\Control\SecurityProviders\SCHANNEL\Ciphers\RC4 64/128')
```

Ref: [Reddit: How do you escape in powershell](https://www.reddit.com/r/PowerShell/comments/34kvyv/how_do_you_escape_in_powershell/)

Answer (score 0):

This works for me:

```
New-Item -Path "HKCU:\Software\My Software\My Version" -Name "Sample key" -Force
```

[image]

Comment: That creates a '128' subfolder within an 'RC4 64' folder for me.
I'm looking to create a subfolder called 'RC4 64/128' under 'Ciphers' :(

Thanks though!

Comment: Don't think that was me, but your solution didn't work so I reworded the question to show I needed both a space and a slash in the folder name. I had to resort to calling a reg file as a hacky work around but if you know a way of doing this that would be very helpful :)